# Fancybox submit form do not close

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to ask for some help. I've been searching a solution for hours...

I've my main file that call and fancybox 2.1.1 ajax frame.

I have a form on my fancybox frame, and when the form is a sucess I want to close the fancybox, so I use `jQuery.fancybox.close();` and it starts to close but the overlay doesn't close (I need to click on it). So I try to add callback on the js call, like afterClose () and beforeClose() (with an alert msg for testing). The alert only show when I click to close the overlay. I also try to add `jQuery('.fancybox-overlay').hide();`, it hide the overlay but I still need a click to refresh my form action.

I read this two post and try the solution, doesn't work : [Here](http://dropthenerd.com/web-development/close-fancybox-when-you-submit-a-form-revisited)

You are my only hope because all work except this double click! Thanks !

Next my code :

Main page code, Popup JS call work fine :

```
jQuery(".popup-style").fancybox ({
            'hideOnContentClick' : true,
            'width' : 710,
            'height' : 'auto',              
            'padding' : 0,
            'beforeClose': function(){                  
                if (verif == "ok") {                        
                    var NAME = document.getElementById("product" + pproductid)
                    NAME.className='bouton unstyle w310';
                    jQuery("#folderid").removeAttr("disabled");
                    jQuery("#foldername").removeAttr("disabled");
                    document.getElementById("product" + pproductid).innerHTML = '<span>Unstyle it!</span>'; 
                    document.getElementById("product" + pproductid).href ='javascript:removeproduct1(pproductid)';        
                    var myTextField = document.getElementById("compteur"+ pproductid);    
                    var precision=parseInt(myTextField.innerHTML);
                    precision =   precision+1;   
                    document.getElementById("compteur"+ pproductid).innerHTML =  precision;
                }                   
            }                       
        });
```

Html call the fancybox

```
<a id="product<?php echo $productid ?>" class="bouton popup-style w310 fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('arithmetic/integer/popupstyle/productid/'.$productid)?>"><span>Style it!</span></a>
```

Popup CODE :

HTML :

```
     <form id="popupform" name="popupform" method="post" >         
     <input type="submit" class="small-btn rounded" value="Style It!"/></a>
```

JS :

```
var verif = "ko";
    var pproductid; 



            jQuery("#popupform").submit(function(){
                verif = "ok";
                pproductid = jQuery("#productid").val();    
                var pfolderid = jQuery("#folderid").val();    
                var pfoldername = jQuery("#foldername").val();     
                var psize = jQuery("#size").val();    
                var pcolor = jQuery("#color").val();     
                var pcategory = 13;//jQuery("#$category").val();      
                var psubcategory = 10;//jQuery("#$subcategory").val();
                //alert("test");
            if (jQuery(".valid-name").val() != "" || jQuery(".valid-id").val() != "select") {

                jQuery.post('http://localhost/magento-sample/index.php/arithmetic/integer/addstyle1',{
                    productid:pproductid,category:pcategory,subcategory:psubcategory,folderid:pfolderid,foldername:pfoldername,size:psize,color:pcolor
                }); 


                    jQuery.fancybox.close();                            
                    //jQuery('.fancybox-ajax').remove();
                    //jQuery('.fancybox-overlay').hide();
                    //jQuery('.fancybox-overlay').style.display=="none"();                      
                    return false;
                    jQuery.fancybox.close();    

            }                           
        });
```

Comment: so fancybox will close only if condition is met ... have you validated the condition values?

Comment: Yes, the condition is validated and even without this condition the jQuery.fancyboy.close() command is not working on this form submit.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Firebug or Developer tools console for errors when closing fancybox? Does it throw any error?

Comment: Hello Mladen, I don't have any errors in the console. I try a simple example with a fancybox.ajax popup and the function close still doesn't work.